# My supervisor refused me to submit after I got the reply from the journal

Tags: publications, advisor

I submit an extended abstract to a high impact journal, and the journal said that my work in the same scope. The supervisor mentioned that this is very different level of research needed and said dont send.The reviewers are too challenging, your paper is also not organised for a XX journal. TBH I feel disappointed, it is not the first time, I do always ridiculed, humiliated in each group meeting never appreciated. This is really weird.

Is this a normal behavior of a supervisor?

Comment: Would you like advice on your professor's feedback, or how they are treating you?

Comment: the latter I already give up and I cannot do anything about their behavior, but it is weird that they view my research as not to the standard and always attacking me in the meeting that my research is risky,

Comment: Then I suggest you edit a little to get the answer you need - right now it would be pretty reasonable to say "Your work may be in scope, but isn't ready for such a high impact journal" is fine feedback. I'm sorry that's happening to you :(

Comment: Is your supervisor a co-author?

Comment: Yes they are, they always has been hostile and their relative also in our group is co-author both has aggressive attitude since I started and always demoralizing. There is also other colleague is encouraged to submit to this journal although I find their work is incremental. My research IMH is addressing something never touched before.

Answer (score 6):

My understanding is that you sent a presubmission inquiry to a prestigious journal; they responded encouraging you to submit. I assume you did this without your supervisor's approval based on their reaction.

You brought this response to your supervisor, but they are encouraging you not to submit there because they don't think the work is of sufficient quality for that journal.

A few things:

1. Your supervisor may be upset you went behind their back and sent an inquiry to the journal, especially if you did this to argue against your supervisor's advice. This reaction may not be fair or warranted, but it is a predictable result.
2. A presubmission inquiry is just that...presubmission. A positive response doesn't mean your work will be accepted, especially with a prestigious journal where acceptance is not the norm.
3. Not all work is suitable for the most prestigious journals. Lots of very excellent work is published elsewhere, and there is nothing wrong with that work.
4. Some, but not all prestigious journals have a substantially different format to other journals in the field. The journal *Science*, for example, where whole articles are barely a page. If you're preparing a manuscript in another format, switching to one of these short-format papers is a lot of work. Other journals may also have restrictive length limits even if they aren't as extreme as Science. Time spent on reformatting could be spent on a new research project instead, if the work is not going to be accepted. This is always a gamble, but sometimes it's worth it and sometimes not.
5. Ordinarily, I'd side with your supervisor on this. They know the field, they know the journals, they have the experience. Yes, it is normal behavior of a supervisor to guide their students towards appropriate publishing venues. I would hope that a supervisor would also explain the specific reasons why a particular project may or may not be suited to a prestigious journal. For example, there are some top journals in my field where *in vitro* work rarely stands on its own. To publish in these journals, it's usually necessary to do a paired *in vivo*/*in vitro* project, where the authors show a mechanism in a dish alongside evidence that the same mechanism is functioning *in vivo*. If I brought a very excellent *in vitro* project to a supervisor, I'd hope that they explain this to me: that we either need to add substantial additional experiments and take an additional year or more working on the project, or publish in a different venue. This may be disappointing, but it's not an example of ridicule.
6. It's certainly possible your supervisor is *not* acting in your best interests, but I don't see how we can determine that here. I'd recommend having someone knowledgeable who you trust, like another professor, look at your work and help you make a judgment.

Comment: I think you started wrong, I have the freedom to submit to what ever journal even my colleague do the same, it happens to know the editor of this journal and working with before and even they asked me where do you plan (I am the one who decide), when they know it is that journal that what happen.

Comment: @Monika Is your supervisor a coauthor on this project, or are you the only author? If you're the only author, then yes it's ultimately your decision (though your supervisor can still help guide you) and my point #1 doesn't apply. The rest does, though.

Comment: Yes, they are a co-author, as I mentioned all my colleague in the same project and same supervisor has the freedom to submit to any venue. I feel they dont have the best interest for me, the next journal is still quite also high impact journal but not like that of course. I sent them what if I got rejected form the second journal.

Comment: I know they dont like me as a person "jealous maybe" and even every meeting they bragging about other paper published in that same journal I got a reply from and always devaluing, and undermining my work even though I have conversation with other specialized professors than my PI and they said the work is interesting and new

Comment: Literally, the day I presented how it work in experiment and simulation, they got angry that I choose something risky and no handled, how non reasonable is this, so yes I doubt that they want me to publish in this journal which is "Science subfield" btw

Comment: "Yes, they are a co-author, as I mentioned all my colleague in the same project and same supervisor has the freedom to submit to any venue" - no, this is incorrect. If you have coauthors, then you can submit **only to venues where all coauthors together agree**.

Comment: Maybe but there is no valid reason to prevent from submission, anyway I will wait to another journal reply and then I can discuss again, I dont want my work to be degraded hopefully.

Comment: @Monika No, not "maybe". You do **need your coauthors' permission to submit**. If you act like that isn't the case, you are going to make people rightfully upset with you.

Comment: Ok, I just sent to the supervisor that I consider another journal with lower impact and asked them what if I got a rejection what I should consider to make sure I submit my work to suitable and high impact journal, is that ok.

Comment: I'd be very upset if my co-author just submitted our work to some journal without consulting me first.

Comment: If you submit a paper to a journal without the approval of the co-author(s), and one of them tells the journal, odds are your paper will be desk rejected. It's usually a policy that all co-authors must agree before you can submit.

Comment: stopping saying our work it is only done by me.

Comment: @Monika You have coauthors, so it isn't only done by you. Maybe major parts of the project are done only by you but if other people can rightfully claim authorship it's theirs, too.